# Connecting to Owin SignalR Hub using Blazor Application

Tags: blazor-server-side, signalr-hub, signalr.client, katana

I have SignalR Hub written in .Net Framework and self-hosted using Owin/Katana.

Now I want to connect the aforementioned Hub in a .Net Core Blazor Web server app,

The problem is in Blazor I have to provide a URL, but Owin/Katana hosted hub does not have a URL to provide.

```
hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.WithUrl(???)
.Build();
```

In .Net Framework I can connect using,

```
var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8081/");
var testHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
```

How can I connect to the same Hub using Blazor Web server app?

Comment: .WithUrl() will be your localhost along with your hub controller name: http://localhost:8081/ChatHub

Comment: No. It will not work. this issue is .Net SignalR and .Net Core SignalR is not compatible.